# Website content not updating even github repository is changed

Tags: git, github

My website content is not updating itself even though git told me everything is merged and updated. 
Here is the url: https://kyloxue.com/
and the repot: https://github.com/alfance/kyloport
The repo is up to date, I just dont understand why the new updated wont show up.

- I cleaned the cache and hard reloaded, tried on fresh computer. not working.
- Source branch is on Master, and all changes are pushed to Master. 
  [image: screenshot of the git setting]
- tried switching the default branch to something else, then switch back. no luck :(

Any help is appreciated! thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. had forgot to npm -d build. 
after I build the bundle package the website is updated. `-`